# Should I say that I need visa sponsorship in my cover letters?

Tags: job-search, cover-letter, australia, visa

I'm an Indonesian citizen but I have lived in Australia for 10 years, spent my high school, university & 2 years post graduate professional work at Australia. I'm looking for a sponsorship to allow me to stay in Australia for at least another 1-2 years before I can get my permanent residency.

So the way I am doing right now is, instead of applying for a job, I am sending my resume & cover letter to companies.

Should I say in my cover letter that I need sponsorship for the job? Or should I just wait until they invite for an interview and let them know face to face?

Personally, I prefer to say it in cover letter in order to avoid them wasting their time (if the company doesn't sponsor employee). But this will blow up my chance of getting the job.

Comment: What visa are you on now? Have you tried calling/sending emails to ask about visa sponsorships?

Comment: 485 Temporary Graduate Visa. No I haven't email to ask for visa sponsorship. Should I tell them I need a sponsorship in my cover letter or should I tell them during the interview?

Comment: Can't you apply for citizenship after you've been there for that long?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I mention in my resume that I don't have a work permit?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/82610/should-i-mention-in-my-resume-that-i-dont-have-a-work-permit)

Comment: @lucasgcb Nope. There is no points awarded for staying in the country for a long time. Its usually assumed that a childs parents would of applied for the citizenship if they stayed in the country for that long.

Answer (score 9):

"But this will blow up my chance of getting the job."

If a company is not in a position to help you with a visa, then even if you get an interview, you won't pass; and you'll have wasted their time, and yours. For larger companies who have several employees on a visa, it won't be an issue.

I recommend you put it in the cover letter.

Answer (score -1):

In an ideal world the answer would be you should, since it is crucial for the company to decide whether to spend its resources interviewing someone they cannot even afford to hire.

But the real recruitment world is unfortunately *very* far from ideal. There is quite a bit of recruiter bias against visa requirements, and I have seen a lot of people get filtered out that way from positions *that would sponsor the visas*.

I would not put that in the cover letter (from experience no one reads those anyway so you might be safe if you do) but mention it during an interview with the actual hiring manager or when asked.

Comment: Do you have experience with this in order to speak for most recruiters?

Comment: The vitriolic comment against recruiters was admittedly unnecessary but the same principle still applies. Pipelines through non-referrals --cold applciations-- tend to get screened by detached recruitment teams or even 3rd party recruiters who sift through large applicant pools for various positions. The volume demands simply filtering candidates on any resemblance of 'undesirability' so a well-intended mention of a sponsorship requirement might severely harm OP's chances even for positions that would be fine with it

Comment: That is not hard to assume, I'm just asking what kind of experience you've had that supports the claim.

Comment: None, take every single word I write with a grain of salt like anything else on this Q&A wiki here.